# Dismiss subView

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have such a code in FirstViewController

```
{
SecondViewController *objComing=[[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:objComing.view];

objComing.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

objComing.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,420, 320, 0);
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
objComing.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 420);

[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

SecoundViewController contains button to close/dismiss. How should look the IBAction connected to button (included in SecoundViewController) to dismiss/remove and hide this overlayer?

Answer (score 1):

In the Close/dismiss button method add the following line to remove the secondviewcontroller subview:

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: It crashes if I added it to method in SecoundViewController.m and gives. "(lldb) "

Comment: It's hard to guess what's going on with the little info you're providing here. Give better details pls.
Doubt this is the issue, but in the code above, I don't see any [objComing release] since you alloc-init it.

Answer (score 0):

[self.view removeFromSuperview];